# selenium driver is launching new tab instead of new window

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[This is a very strange behavior happening only on my laptop, not on other laptops.
when I call chrome driver in my script(problem with only chrome, Firefox is working fine) it is opening in a new tab in existing window and scripts will not run.if I close the current chrome window and run the script scripts will run in a window which has all the extensions
I tried deleting chrome from regedit and reinstall chrome and exe files.
please don't say code issue because same codes I am running on all other laptops work fine.

Snapshot of the browsing session : [Browsing Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwZL1.png)

Image of the URL : [URL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyeEL.jpg)

Please see the images in image one selenium launches a new tab in existing window
Image 2: I close chrome window and run the script, it is opening in the default window

my scripts are running on chrome window where I save my passwords not in a new window without cache or passwords
any help is appreciated
This is my code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\myapp\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in");
```

Comment: click on ist paragraph to see the 1st image: when I run the script without closing existing chrome window, click on" enter image descriptions here "to see the 2nd image: when I run the script after closing chrome window

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any such error in your code block perhaps due to installation of some **extension** or some **add-on** the *Chrome Browser* related schema/chrome got modified. A solution will be as follows :

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown{}` method to *close* and *destroy* the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: This is also not working. I think this is some chrome driver setup issues ( i deleted home page setup, new URL setup.new tab setup,...of chrome  from regedit (windows+R "regedit")but nothing seems to be solving the issue)

Answer (score 0):

can you try cleanup existing running chrome.exe. you can call this clean up step before setting up system property

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
```

Comment: it is working.What it is doing is killing existing chrome window(even chromium too) and launch the main window itself (the one with add-ons) it is not launching any new windows

Answer (score 0):

Modify simply to initialize your `ChromeDriver`. Use `ChromeOptions`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\myapp\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--test-type");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in");
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is also not working .the same result as earlier